# capture repetition of letters in a word with regex

Tags: regex, r

I'm trying to detect conditions where words have repetition of letters, and i would like to replace such matched conditions with the repeated letter. The text is in Hebrew. For instance, `שללללוווווםםםם` should just become `שלום`.
Basically,when a letter repeats itself 3 times or more - it should be detected and replaced.

I want to use the regex expression for r `gsub`.

```
df$text <- gsub("?", "?", df$text)
```

Comment: Be careful not to ask for packages as that's against the rules. It'll get your question closed at best and your question-asking privilege restricted at worse. However you can ask that at the Software Recommendations SE site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
> x = "שללללוווווםםםם"
> gsub("(.)\\1{2,}", "\\1", x)
#[1] "שלום"
```

**NOTE** :- It will replace any character (*not just hebrew*) which is repeated more than three times.

or following for only letter/digit from any language

```
> gsub("(\\w)\\1{2,}", "\\1", x)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you plan to only remove repeating characters from the Hebrew script (keeping others), I'd suggest:

```
s <- "שללללוווווםםםם .........         שללללוווווםםםם"
gsub("(\\p{Hebrew})\\1{2,}", "\\1", s, perl=TRUE)
```

See the [regex demo in R](http://ideone.com/heOgPd)

**Details**:

- `(\\p{Hebrew})` -  Group 1 [**capturing**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) a character from Hebrew script (as `\p{Hebrew}` is a [**Unicode property/category class**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#script))
- `\\1{2,}`  - 2 or more (due to `{2,}` [**limiting quantifier**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit)) same characters stored in Group 1 buffer (as `\\1` is a [**backreference**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) to Group 1 contents).